# Trigonometry finding constant with angle

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(x)=P$

(i) Find $\sin(x)$

I try $\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{(1-p^2)}}{1}$

(ii) Find $\sin(90+x)$

(iii) Find $\sin(180-x)$

(iv) Find $\sin(360-x)$

How to solve for part(ii)(iii)(iv)

Comment: Do you know the extended definitions of sine/cosine/tangent to handle angles that are greater than 90?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Pythagorean Identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$?

Comment: I am familiar with the formula but i can't use the formula on this paper exam. And need to use a sketch or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions can be simplified as

1. Cosx
2. Sinx

3.-Sinx

1. Can be found out using $sin^2x +cos^2x =1$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sum and difference formulas:

$\sin(\alpha\pm\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta\pm\cos\alpha\cos\beta$